# Delete vs operator delete (and void pointer)

Tags: c++, destructor, void-pointers, delete-operator

Does `delete ptr` differ from `operator delete(ptr)` only in this, that `delete` calls `ptr` destructor? Or in other words, does `delete ptr` first call a destructor of `ptr` and then `operator delete(ptr)` to free allocated memory? Then is `delete ptr` technically equivalent to the following:

```
T * ptr = new T;

//delete ptr equivalent:
ptr->~T();
::operator delete(static_cast<void *>(ptr));
```

?

Comment: Yes, that's the only difference, besides the fact that you can overload `operator delete`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`delete ptr` will do overload resolution for `operator delete`, so it may not call the global `::operator delete`

But otherwise, yes. The `delete` operator calls the relevant destructor, if any, and then calls `operator delete`.